# Any way to remedy EF slow startup?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm using a legacy `ObjectContext` for my EF 5 project.  The project has grown significantly since inception, as projects do, and now we are sitting at around 400 tables, plus a handful of views that are also included in the edmx model.  It all works fine... but the startup time from cold is getting to be a real problem, both for programmers who are trying to debug stuff and have to wait upwards of a minute before the web site is ready to run, and for testers and users of QA and production builds, who likewise have to wait a long time before each new deployment is ready for use.

We also have a development road map that is going to add ever more tables to our DB.  So this problem is only going to get worse.

Is there something we can do to speed up our startup times?  Would switching to `DbContext` help?  And if so, how disruptive would that be for existing code that is using the `ObjectContext`?

Comment: I cheat... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550584/asp-mvc-4-x-recompile-project-every-time-how-to-fix/25551608

Comment: @MarcGravell, I just read your answer there and I get the gist, but not how it's done in practice.  Could you please flesh out exactly how you would do this?  Perhaps here as an answer?

Comment: DBContext is just a wrapper around ObjectContext. You can still get a reference to ObjectContext through DBContext. So I doubt that will speed up anything.

Comment: Something to consider is how are you loading your objects? Lazy or eager? Lazy can create an extra call to the DB when using a related object. Try turning it off a bit. E.g. instead of playing around with IQueryable change to List's.

Comment: @PaulZahra, all relationship properties are lazy loaded.  But the slowness is not when loading the db; it's the startup time to cache the data model, plus the time making the first connection to the db.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes there are a lot of things you can do to speed up your start times such as using Pre-Generated Views (only doable with DbContext), using Foreign Key associations to reduce view generation cost and moving your model to a separate assembly.

e.g.
"When your model is included directly in your application's project and you generate views through a pre-build event or a T4 template, view generation and validation will take place whenever the project is rebuilt, even if the model wasn't changed. If you move the model to a separate assembly and reference it from your application's project, you can make other changes to your application without needing to rebuild the project containing the model."

[Read this lengthy MSDN Performance Considerations for EF4, EF5, EF6 article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx)

DBContext is just a wrapper around ObjectContext. You can still get a reference to ObjectContext through DBContext. So I doubt that will speed up anything, if anything it will probably slow things down.